# Turn off Worker Tier App when SQS is empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an Elastic Beanstalk Application set to Worker Tier where a SQS is sending it messages to process. Sometimes my SQS is empty, and when its empty I dont want my application to be running, and costing me money.

My applications are always "Green" except for short periods of time where it sets type to WARN for 2minutes, and then it sets it to "Info" (Green) for multiple hours again. On idle my Monitoring tab says that it has a CPU load of about 7.7%.

So what I want is that when my SQS is empty for lets say 60 seconds. The EC2 instance shuts down until a new SQS message is added. How is this possible? Or do I have to keep paying for a EC2 instance that is not doing "anything"?

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to setup autoscale policies, and this document gives you a pretty good overview of the process.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/as-using-sqs-queue.html

One thing to keep in mind however, shutting down an ec2 instance after 60 seconds of inactivity may end up costing you more than keeping it running all the time.

As an example:

Assume your workload is such that a new item enters the queue every 2 minutes, and they each take 45 seconds to process.

In this case, whats going to happen is that you will spin up an instance, it will work for 45 seconds, wait for 60 seconds and then shutdown because the SQS queue is empty. 15 seconds later a new instance will spin up to process the queue item that arrived at 2 minutes from the first.

So your policies will end up spinning up a total of 30 new instances in one hour period and because every time you spin up an instance you get billed for the full hour, you will pay for 30 hours of instance time for every 1 hour of work you do - probably not what you wanted.

So yes, what you want to do is possible, but may not be a good idea depending on your workload. Remember - spin instances up fast when you need them, and turn them off slowly since you've already paid for a full hour.

You really need to figure out the likely pattern that work will arrive in the queue and then design a solution around that. It may end up being cheaper to always have one instance running, even a small one, and spin up extra instances if the SQS queue gets backed up past a certain point (and you are still going to want to make sure you don't start and stop that second instance too often).

Comment: In my case it loads 50'000 messages at a time, but only a few times per week or maximum once per day. So I think in my specific scenario that won't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using SNS notifications and Lambda functions. This way you will be able to pay only for each message processed. You will not have to worry about turning your application on, off or scaling depending on the number of pending messages.

You can get more details on how to do this integration in the following link: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-lambda.html

Also, remember that Lambda functions support multiple event sources (such as Dynamodb and S3 Bucket). You can see the complete list in the following link:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html

Happy coding!